# Replacement for HttpHandlers in ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net-core

I have read that HttpHandlers is not part of ASP.NET 5 (vNext)Is there a replacement tha can be used instead that works the same.

I am looking for a solution that can load an image based on id from a entity. And if that image doesn't exist, a [Non Image] Image should be shown instead. This works perfect with http handler. But I don't see a good solution in ASP.NET vNext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The replacement of `HttpHandler` and `HttpModule` is middleware. You can easily wrote a middleware to handle your issue.
However in your particular case a custom `Image TagHelper` can be more usefull.
[TagHelper sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/tree/master/samples/TagHelperSample.Web)
[Middleware sample](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/master/samples/Builder.Middleware.Web)

Comment: Thanks. I wrote my own Middleware (I wanted it to work in some javascript code too...) and that works!!