# .NET IHttpHandler heading for obsolescence?

Tags: asp.net, .net

We use IHttpHandler's for a number of things in our Web applications. We are considering expanding their use in some new development we are doing.

Registering and using HTTP handlers is our preferred method (we are currently using IIS 8.0), but it seems that Web.config is on it's way out.

Is IHttpHandler on it's way to obsolescence? If so, is there a better way to get parallel functionality?

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29690982/replacement-for-httphandlers-in-asp-net-vnext